# I am using an Iframe to embed loom videos in my app and I want to trigger an event on play of the video

Tags: video, iframe

I am using an Iframe to embed loom videos in my app and I want to trigger an event on play of the video. I tried different methods but didn't work. Is there any specific method which is secure with iframe to use to get events from loom player ?

I tried by attaching different events listeners. One i tried by message communication from parent to iframe but this is risky. I don't want any security issues.
I find loom SDK. There are two actually. One is record-sdk and embed-sdk. Record sdk is for video reacording and embed-sdk is bit confusing.